# intercepting grpc calls for Android app is not working

Tags: android, proxy, grpc, android-networking, android-vpn-service

I have an android application which uses grpc to fetch configs and home page content(live data) and REST for deeper engagement views.

My requirements

- get all network traffic(sent/received) of my application
- I want to see size of all sent and received
- I want this to be automated so that at the end of automated tests i can get this data
- i want to get full path of endpoints (eg while fetching asset like webp , i need the full url)

Solutions which i tried

- I have tried pcapdroid(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emanuelef.remote_capture&hl=en_US) but that doesn't give full url it just gives endpoint
- Mitm proxy - it gives only gives for REST , i dont get TLS exception or no data for grpc connection. my grpc endpoint is not pinned